# Is there a noun for "kind/sweet" girl?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Example sentence:

> I wondered why such a __ like Mary had fallen for such a jerk like
>   Tom.

I thought of *sweetheart* but I think the word is more associated to "attractive" woman.

Comment: I beg to differ - 'sweetheart' does not necessarily imply that one is attractive - one of the meanings is 'a particularly lovable or pleasing person or thing (Merriam-Webster). I think sweetheart or darling would be an appropriate word to describe such a girl. Having said that, User26328's answer seems to be the best word to describe such a girl.

Comment: [absorbing, alluring, amiable, appealing, attractive, bewitching,
captivating, charismatic, charming, choice, cute, dainty, delectable,
delicate, delightful, desirable, electrifying, elegant, enamoring,
engaging, engrossing, enthralling, entrancing, eye-catching, fascinating,
fetching, glamorous, graceful, infatuating, inviting, irresistible,
likable, lovable, lovely, magnetizing, nice, pleasant, pleasing,
provocative, rapturous, ravishing, seducing, seductive, sweet, tantalizing,
tempting, titillating, winning, winsome](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sweet?s=t).

Comment: There are zillions and zillions and zillions of possibilities here. What did your previous research show and why did you find none of those suitable?

Comment: @tchrist I think alex is after a noun, not an adjective, in order to retain the symmetry with the description of "Tom".

Comment: sweetheart is fine there.  But isn't this just an ELL question?

Comment: @tchrist While all of those are (near-)synomyms for nice, a lot of them relate to appearance. A word to describe personality would work better.

Comment: Perhaps "dear" or "darling" might work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would suggest the word [**angel**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/angel), which is more often than not used of women and girls in precisely this manner:

> A person of exemplary conduct or virtue.

<sup>oxforddictionaries.com</sup>

Comment: Please include relevant information from links, so that if the link ceases to work in the future, the answer still has the information. Additionally, in this case it is important to highlight which one of many definitions is the appropriate one. I've edited the info in for this answer as a demonstration.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think _angel_ is gender-specific.  A guy can be called an angel, without any stain on his masculinity.

Comment: @Malvolio I do think calling a man an "angel" would imply the softer more empathetic and less fierce demeanor that 30 years ago we might call "effeminate" but now need a term for that is gender neutral, as a modern woman could be just as likely be as fierce and stoically brave as was formerly considered a masculine ideal/expectation.  "Angel" is worlds apart from say.. "one with testosterone"

Comment: *angel* also pairs well with *fallen* for a double-meaning, unless you're averse to puns.

Comment: Are there even women angels? Not a Christian so idk

Comment: @Tom22 Clearly you are not reading [the right kind of angelic novels](http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/42275.Best_Adult_Angel_Books).

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Angels are genderless in the Christian faith, though usually depicted male.

Comment: @Rhythmatic Even, like, Gabriel?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai yes, see [this link](https://carm.org/are-angels-male-or-female-in-the-bible) for a brief look at the topic.

Answer (score 3):

**[Real sweetie](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sweetie)** or just **[sweetie](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/sweetie)** is often used to refer to a person who has a kind and pleasant nature.

Sweetie alone is also often used for romantic relations, but calling someone a "real sweetie" is almost always used to mean they are nice, good-natured, or friendly.

"That cashier was a real sweetie, she was so helpful and never stopped smiling!"

"You should meet my cousin Verdelia, she's a real sweetie, and she's single."

"I'd like to know

Comment: And probably you should consider sweetie as short for "sweetheart".

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast this is true, I hear both words used frequently in a similar way, but "real sweetheart" is more likely to be used sarcastically to mean an unpleasant person.